# Newbie: Why the Color of the Background Pattern .png image is not changing?

Tags: html, css

I have browsed many questions here but none of them is relevant to this query.

I am just trying to Change the color of a Background .png image. But its color is Not Changing. Then, I convert the .png image To .gif format & tried again. But this time too, the color of .gif image Not change.

Image Link = http://www.flickr.com/photos/34259785@N00/6803476044/

Please tell that Why the color of image is Not Changing. Following is the code: -

```
background-color: #3399FF;
background-image: url("images/diagonal_striped_brick.gif");
```

Comment: Ae you sure the image has transparency?

Comment: sorry, I have no idea, how to make it transparent?

Answer (score 1):

The image does not have background transparency.  The white background of the image is a solid color, and will not let the background color of the page show through.

You may be able to edit the image using an image editor and try to convert the white background of the image to full transparency.

Answer (score 1):

Just made a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ywq5n/). The image you are using is **not** transparent.

---

Update: How to make the image transparent?

- Open the image with an image editor like photoshop.
- Changed the opacity value of image
- Save it as .png for better quality.

Now, the code from above will be able to give you the desired affect.

Comment: I see, how to make it transparent?

Comment: Thanks. I did it with a image, but it is'nt yield desired result.

Comment: @user514892, Please explain, what you mean by desired result.

Comment: I just wanted to make a gif image, similar to other gif, but cant do it, thats all.

Comment: @user514892, What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

.jpg files cannot have transparent. For that use png files with an alpha channel.

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/AbHjK/4/) for a version in which a colour is overlaid on top of the image.

Comment: It's not `repeat: repeat;`, it's `background-repeat: repeat;`.

Comment: Thanks! Just made an oversight. Updated my answer.

Comment: This doesn't even have `background-color` in it…

Comment: Oh sorry it is such a poorly worded question I did not understand what he was asking. I will edit my answer now

Comment: Updated answer providing semi-solution